# How to verify table element and click on other element with Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to create a **scraper** that enters a website and downloads an XML file containing a balance sheet from real estate funds.

With the code below, I enter a website for a specific fund with document number 07000400000146 (at the end of URL), filter the documents with a search bar on the website, and click to download the first document in the table using XPath.

```
driver.get('https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/abrirGerenciadorDocumentosCVM?cnpjFundo=07000400000146')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(f'input[type="search"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(f'input[type="search"]').send_keys('informe mensal')
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tblDocumentosEnviados"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[10]/div/a[2]/i').click()
```

How can I create a boolean expression to discover if a row is of 03/2020 or 02/2020 or 01/2020, in column "Data de Referência" and then download all the available files for each corresponding dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a list like `datelist=[ '03/2020','02/2020','01/2020']` this and check the dates are available on the webpage using below xpath option.If the date available this will click and download else tell no dates available.
Use `try..except` block.ignore `sleep()` use `WebDriverWait`()

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/abrirGerenciadorDocumentosCVM?cnpjFundo=07000400000146')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type="search"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type="search"]').send_keys('informe mensal')
datelist=[ '03/2020','02/2020','01/2020']
for dates in datelist:
    try:
       WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//table[@id='tblDocumentosEnviados']//td[text()='"+ dates + "']/following-sibling::td[5]//a[@title='Download do Documento']"))).click()
       print('file downloaded with dates available ' + dates)
    except:
       print("No such dates available " + dates)
```

This will print on console like this.

```
No such dates available 03/2020
file downloaded with dates available 02/2020
file downloaded with dates available 01/2020
```

---

Updated code with status `Ativo`

```
driver.get('https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/abrirGerenciadorDocumentosCVM?cnpjFundo=07000400000146')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type="search"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type="search"]').send_keys('informe mensal')
datelist=[ '03/2020','02/2020','01/2020']
for dates in datelist:
    try:
       WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//table[@id='tblDocumentosEnviados']//td[text()='"+ dates +"']/following-sibling::td[.//span[text()='Ativo']]/following-sibling::td//a[@title='Download do Documento']"))).click()
       print('file downloaded with dates available ' + dates)
    except:
       print("No such dates available " + dates)
```

Comment: Your answer does exactly what my question was asking!

Comment: I've noticed that i didnt add on the question the requirement for the 'status' column, i need for the 'status' to be "Ativo". Could you help me with where i need to add this to the code above?

Comment: can you help me on this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/61686680/12880475

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code to download your pdf

```
driver.get('https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/abrirGerenciadorDocumentosCVM?cnpjFundo=07000400000146')
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
elemnt=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'label > input')))
elemnt.send_keys('informe mensal')

mylist=[ '03/2020','02/2020','01/2020']
for list in mylist:
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                                                    "//td[text()='" + list + "']//following-sibling::td//a[@title='Download do Documento']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button);
```