# Python Selenium iterating through table and click correspondingly each row

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to iterate through a table and download xml files, but, i am only downloading the contents of the first element in the table. How can I iterate correctly to download the content from each row ?

Where should I include `row` after `for row in table:` to irerate correctly?

```
from selenium import webdriver
options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/abrirGerenciadorDocumentosCVM?cnpjFundo=30983020000190')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(f'input[type="search"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(f'input[type="search"]').send_keys('rendimentos')
time.sleep(1)
table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='tblDocumentosEnviados']//tr")
for row in table:
try:
WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//table[@id='tblDocumentosEnviados']//td[text()='Rendimentos e Amortizações']/following-sibling::td[.//span[text()='Ativo']]/following-sibling::td//a[@title='Download do Documento']"))).click()
x = x + 1
print(x)
except:
print('except')
```

EDIT

I need to add the row iteration in this line to be successful:

```
                try:
                    WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                                                               "//table[@id='tblDocumentosEnviados']//td[text()='Rendimentos e Amortizações']/following-sibling::td[.//span[text()='Ativo']]/following-sibling::td//a[@title='Download do Documento']"))).click()
```

Comment: for row in table: (in the loop body) you don't seem to consume the 'row', you are using a static xPath, that is not updated in each loop?

Comment: The table has many rows, in this case 5 rows. I need to download one file for each of the rows, but i am only getting the first row file. What should i add / remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code this will target the row you are after.

```
options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/abrirGerenciadorDocumentosCVM?cnpjFundo=30983020000190')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type="search"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type="search"]').send_keys('rendimentos')
time.sleep(1)
table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='tblDocumentosEnviados']//tr")
print(len(table))
for row in range(len(table)):
   try:
      WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//table[@id='tblDocumentosEnviados']//tr[" + str(row) + "]//td[text()='Rendimentos e Amortizações']/following-sibling::td[.//span[text()='Ativo']]/following-sibling::td//a[@title='Download do Documento']"))).click()
      x = row + 1
      print(x)
   except:
      print('except')
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using selenium to download the file I prefer to us BeautifulSoup.
Change your table to the one below, to get the `html`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='tblDocumentosEnviados']")

table_html = table[0].get_attribute('outerHTML')
table_html = BeautifulSoup(table_html, 'lxml')
list_url = []

for tr in table_html.find_all('tr'):
    for td in tr.find_all('td'):
        file_anchor = td.find('a', {'title': 'Download do Documento'})
        if file_anchor:
            complete_url = 'https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/{}'.format(file_anchor.get('href'))
            list_url.append(complete_url)
```

Now you can use request.get to download the file, Hope this helps !!!

file download - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/downloading-files-from-web-using-python

Comment: I appreciate your help, but, all my codes runs on selenium. After running it smoothly with selenium i pretend to use BS4, but, for now, i need to download using selenium and there is just one step missing here wich i cant figure it out.

Comment: Okay ,If i understood it correctly,  you just have to use Beautiful Soup for the file download part the easiest & clean solution  for the rest you have to use selenium only.

Comment: I have another code that extracts files from the same website, but filtering other documents. I edited my question with the line of code that does the part of clicking the buttom to download